# HART; PID Loop via PC & HART modem

Tags: pid-controller

I have a couple of not-very-critical process control loops where the flow sensors can transmit a 4-20 mA signal & the HART protocol.

I want to control some valves via a simple PID loop. Is it possible to implement the PID logic via a PC? How would I go about it, any thoughts / ideas?

A HART Modem  (I think also known as a FSK Modem or a Bell 202) seems not that expensive. But I'm not sure what software etc. I'd need to use on the PC to set up the PID logic. Is this fairly standardized or I'd have to stick to vendor specific propitiatory applications.

e.g. In  the schematic below what are my options to impliment the PID  / logging logic on the "PC Control Station" part of the schematic. Are there any well known programs that I should be aware of? Would something like MATLAB or Labview be a good fit for this?

[image]

Basically, I want to avoid re-inventing the wheel if at all possible. The idea is to avoid the large fixed cost of a full blown DCS or PLC system which seems the norm.

Again, the application isn't very exacting & safety etc. are not a concern.

Additional motivation was this article snippet:

> **Don’t Overlook Control Opportunities **
>   While most facilities use HART
>   for applications related to device configuration and maintenance,
>   users also should look for opportunities to use HART data for process
>   monitoring as well. For example, in applications where conditions such
>   as temperature, pressure and levels change relatively slowly, users
>   can reduce the number of instruments they need in the field by
>   acquiring multiple variables from a single device. Hotard points to
>   tank farms as being ideal sites in which to make use of HART for
>   applications such as inventory monitoring. (see accompanying story).
>   In relatively small operations, users can set up modest, but effective
>   SCADA systems that utilize HART technology, says Mactek’s Holmes. “You
>   could continuously monitor up to eight points using a PC equipped with
>   eight USB HART modems. That’s very do-able,” says Holmes. “For
>   software, you could use a dedicated data acquisition package such as
>   Wonderware’s InTouch software, or something as basic as a Microsoft
>   Excel spreadsheet. I think there are plenty of operations such as
>   bakeries or small specialty chemical plants that can’t justify
>   spending the money for a large control system. But with HART input and
>   a PC, you can build yourself a quick and dirty DCS,” he adds.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the HART Modem will get the process value into the computer. Depending on what you choose to use as a controller and an actuator you could make this work, but it **won't** be an industrial standard process control loop in terms of reliability or perhaps performance, as Windows is not a real-time operating system (but it may be good enough).

One approach is to make a controller with your favorite software such as MATLAB/Simulink, LabView, raw coding in C (for the intrepid and/or old-school).

You'll have to figure out how to control the valves from your PC (not shown in your block diagram). And if you get the BSOD on the PC make sure that there is no undue ill effects on people or property.

Personally, I think you'd be better off buying a process controller with a serial interface (and a suitable output) and use the PC as a supervisory system rather than putting it into the process control loop.

Comment: Thanks. So, for one, the application isn't mission critical. Currently it is being manually controlled. So the lack of an RTOS won't be a huge drawback.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you had in mind when you said "buying a process controller with a serial interface ". At one end of the spectrum I see the quite expensive DCS systems. But standalone controllers seem rare & quite disappointing for the cost.

Comment: Thinking of something like [this](http://www.factorycontrols.com.au/_literature_107780/E5AR_Process_Controller) with 4-20mA input.

Comment: Thanks. I've explored those but they seem limiting. e.g. That model can control max two PID loops with max two 4-20 mA inputs, no logging, no advanced functions & would cost me approx. $500. That doesn't sound too tempting & hence the interest in exploring PC based solutions.